# Numpy error seeting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have the following code and somehow I get the same error over and over and I don't know why or how I can fix it.

```py
import pickle

import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score


data_dict = pickle.load(open('./data.pickle', 'rb'))

data = np.asarray(data_dict['data'])
labels = np.asarray(data_dict['labels'])

model = RandomForestClassifier()

model.fit(x_train, y_train)

y_predict = model.predict(x_test)

score = accuracy_score(y_predict, y_test)

print('{}% of samples were classified correctly !'.format(score * 100))

f = open('model.p', 'wb')
pickle.dump({'model': model}, f)
f.close()
```

This is the error I get:

```py
/home/PycharmProjects/SignLanguage/train_classifier.py:13: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  data = np.asarray(data_dict['data'])
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'list'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/PycharmProjects/SignLanguage/train_classifier.py", line 21, in <module>
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)
  File "/home/PycharmProjects/SignLanguage/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 1151, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/PycharmProjects/SignLanguage/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py", line 348, in fit
    X, y = self._validate_data(
  File "/home/PycharmProjects/SignLanguage/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 621, in _validate_data
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
  File "/home/PycharmProjects/SignLanguage/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 1147, in check_X_y
    X = check_array(
  File "/home/PycharmProjects/SignLanguage/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 917, in check_array
    array = _asarray_with_order(array, order=order, dtype=dtype, xp=xp)
  File "/home/PycharmProjects/SignLanguage/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_array_api.py", line 380, in _asarray_with_order
    array = numpy.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried to install np 1.21.6, didn't solve the error. I tried to install np 1.21.1, didn't solve the problem either. I also tried to rewrite the declaration of data to:

```py
data =  np.asarray([np.asarray(d) for d in data_dict['data']]) # doesn't work
```

Also, when I specify the `dtype` like this:

```
data =  np.asarray(data_dict['data'], dtype=float)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2912,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

Code for data_dict :

```py
import mediapipe as mp
import cv2
import os
import pickle
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mp_hands = mp.solutions.hands
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_drawing_styles = mp.solutions.drawing_styles

hands = mp_hands.Hands(static_image_mode=True, min_detection_confidence=0.3)

DATA_DIR = "./data"

data = []
labels = []

for dir_ in os.listdir(DATA_DIR):
    for img_path in os.listdir(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, dir_)):
        data_aux = []

        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, dir_, img_path))
        img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        results = hands.process(img_rgb)
        if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for hand_landmarks in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                for i in range(len(hand_landmarks.landmark)):
                    x = hand_landmarks.landmark[i].x
                    y = hand_landmarks.landmark[i].y
                    data_aux.append(x)
                    data_aux.append(y)

            data.append(data_aux)
            labels.append(dir_)

f = open('data.pickle', 'wb')
pickle.dump({'data': data, 'labels': labels}, f)
f.close()
```

if I try **@hpaulj** `np.array(data)` I get the following warning:

```
VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  np.array(data)
```

And the output of the print statement looks like this:

```
[(42,), (42,), (42,), (42,), (42,), (42,), (42,), (42,), (42,), (42,), (42,), (42,), (42,), (42,), (42,), (42,), (42,), (42,), (42,), (42,), (42,), (42,), (42,), (42,), (42,)]
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/PycharmProjects/SignLanguage/train_classifier.py", line 16, in <module>
    data =  np.asarray(data_dict['data'], dtype=float)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2912,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

Comment: What are the shapes of `x_train` and `y_train`?

Comment: You need to examine `data_dict['data']`.  What is it?  Array? list? What does it contain?  The code/errors are confusing.  Where does `x_train`, `y_train` come from?  Relation to `data_dict`?  Most likely something, or other, has a mix of data elements, or items that vary in size or shape.  This isn't a problem with numpy versions; it's a problem with the data that we know nothing about.

Comment: I can add the code for creating data_dict.

Comment: And x_train would look sth like this: array([[4, 5],
       [0, 1],
       [6, 7]])
y_train like this:
[2, 0, 3]

and the test arrays would look like this:
x: array([[2, 3],
       [8, 9]])
y: [1, 4]
for example

Comment: And my data_dict['data'] looks like this: 536, 0.9088003039360046, 0.48477232456207275, 0.87766635417938, [...] 0.4633995294570923, 0.6819579005241394, 0.4674365520477295, 0.7289001941680908, 0.4705360233783722, 0.7637642621994019, 0.42224380373954773, 0.6048421263694763, 0.4277583956718445, 0.6780377626419067, 0.42316964268684387, 0.6603876352310181, 0.42096760869026184, 0.6366013288497925, 0.39536792039871216, 0.6151334643363953, 0.4052458107471466, 0.6753289103507996, 0.40337082743644714, 0.6603569388389587, 0.40039676427841187, 0.6392402052879333]]

Comment: Please don't use comments to clarify. Code and data is hard to read in comments. [Edit] your question instead.

Comment: Obviously we can't do much with your creation code, since it makes a list from `cv2` reads, and we don't have the relevant images.  Right before the `pickle.dump`, try doing `np.array(data)`.  Does that work, or does it give the same error.  You/we need to know what exactly is in `data`.  Not the numbers, but the objects, lists or arrays, and the relevant len or shape.  You can't make an array from such a list if it contains a mix of objects/lists/arrays that vary in size!

Comment: `print([np.asarray(d).shape for d in data_dict['data']]`?

Comment: I Edited my question and added the output. It still isn't working